# How to change the version of php I downloaded using web platform

Tags: php, iis, web-platform-installer, web-platforms

Im new to this, I have IIS up and running and I downloaded the PHP version I thought I wanted. But now I want to download a different version, how do I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Just download a new version installer and overwrite. After you are done with environment preparation - start writing code.

Comment: What if I want to install an older version?